# How can a char pointer be initialized with a string (Array of characters) but an int pointer not with an array of integer?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, pointers

How can `char` pointer be initialized with a string (Array of characters) but an `int` pointer not with a array of integer?

When I tried this

```
int* a={1,2,3,4,5};
```

It gives an error saying

> error: scalar object ‘a’ requires one element in initializer

But,

```
char* name="mikhil"
```

works perfectly.

Comment: You can do this:     int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

Comment: _"But char* `name="mikhil"` works perfectly"_ No, it does not - it's wrong in C++ and **won't compile**. So, are we talking about C or C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of you're trying to initialize an `int *` with

```
  {1,2,3,4,5};
```

it is wrong because `{1,2,3,4,5};`, as-is, is not an *array of integers*. It is a brace enclosed list of initializer. This can be used to initialize an `int` array (individual elements of the array, to be specific), but not a pointer. **An array is not a pointer and vice-versa.**

However, you can make use of a [compound literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html#Compound-Literals) to initialize an `int *`, like

```
int * a = (int []){1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: Doesn't this only work in C and not in C++

Comment: @KentKostelac It's a gcc (and clang?) extension in c++, so it's not standard. It also looks like it leaves a dangling pointer.

Comment: your suggested method gives error "taking address of temporary array"

Answer (score 9):

Because these are the rules (standards) of the language. There's nothing telling you it's possible to initialize a pointer with an array like this, for example, the following is also illegal:

```
char* name={'m', 'i', 'k', 'h', 'i', 'l', 0};
```

A literal string gets its own treatment and is not defined just as an array of characters.

Comment: You're right, but this does not _answer_ this particular question. There's a basic difference in the use of the initializer here.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, the language allows char * (or, preferably, const char *) to be initialized with a string.  This is because it is a very common usage, and it has been possible since C.  You shouldn't really modify the string value (of course, that's a separate debate).

With an int, if you initialize an int a[5], it is expected you might change the values.  The initialized values will be copied into your array (compiler optimizations not withstanding), and you can change them how you see fit.  If int *a was allowed to initialize this way, what would it be pointing to? It isn't really clear, so the standard doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 1):

the language dont support null terminator to int arrays , which is since compiler would have ambiguity that is that null terminator or 0 in int array...

it is the same reason due to which

`cout<<anystring;` give complete array of character i.e. complete string
and this dont

`cout<<a;` for a 1-d int array a...infact it gives an error message and dont prints the complete 1-d array...

upvote if i somewhere satisfied / solved your query...

Comment: `'\0'` is just a character with value `0` that can be promoted to `int`. That aside, I don't see how null terminators apply to this. The issue is that `{ 1, 2, 3}` is not an array.